# ¿Cómo se representa un cilindro parabólico en python?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Estoy aprendiendo a graficar pero no encuentro modo de hacer esta figura en concreto.

Estoy usando `matplotlib`

Comment: ¿Cual es la ecuación del cilindro parabólico?

Comment: ¿Qué biblioteca usas para graficar? ¿Matplotlib? ¿Sabes graficar otras figuras en 3D con esa bibloteca? ¿Puedes poner algo de código de partida sobre el cual podamos retocar?

Comment: sí, uso matplotlib y la ecuación podría ser x**2-100*y**2+y = f

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que usar una proyección 3D, como la que te proporciona la biblioteca `mpl_toolkits.mplot3d`.

La idea es la siguiente:

1. Generas vectores `x` e `y` que tengan por así decir las "divisiones" en cada uno de los respectivos ejes x,y. Por ejemplo `x` podría tener números entre -3 y 3, espaciados entre sí 0.5. Para esto puedes usar `arange()`, y análogamente para `y`. En este ejemplo estos vectores tendrían 12 elementos cada uno de ellos.
2. Creas una malla usando `np.meshgrid(x,y)`. Esto crea una especie de "producto cartesiano" entre todos los valores de `x` y de `y`. Así, por ejemplo, existiría el punto (-3,-3), y el (-3, -2.5), etc...  Esta malla tendría por tanto 12*12 = 144 elementos, pero dispuesto en matriz. Lo que retorna `np.meshgrid()` es una tupla cuyo primer elemento es la parte `x` de cada uno de los elementos de esa matriz, y el segundo sería la parte `y`. Llamemos a cada una de estas matrices `X` e `Y` respectivamente.
3. Para cada elemento de esa malla evalúas la función `f` para el par `(x,y)` de cada punto. Eso te genera otra matriz bidimensional de 144 elementos que llamaremos `Z`, que nos da la altura de cada punto de la curva a pintar.
4. Usando la proyección 3d de matplotlib, creamos el `plot_surface()` pasándole como parámetros `X`, `Y` y `Z`.

Este sería el código que hace lo antes descrito:

```
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D  
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Definición de la función f a plotear
f = lambda x,y: x**2-100*y**2+y

# 1. Generar x e y
x = y = np.arange(-3.0, 3.0, 0.5)

# 2. Generar la malla
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)

# 3. Evaluar f en cada punto de la malla y generar Z
zs = np.array(f(np.ravel(X), np.ravel(Y)))
Z = zs.reshape(X.shape)

# 4. Pintar el resultado

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(X,Y,-Z, alpha=0.7)
```

Notas:

- La función `np.ravel()` sirve para "aplanar" la matriz `X` convirtiéndola en una mera secuencia de valores, que hace más simple evaluar `f` como una operación vectorizada, para no tener que itera. El resultado, en `zs` sería un vector de 144 elementos, que volvemos a reordenar como matriz de 12x12 mediante `zs.reshape()`
- A `plot_surface()` le he pasado `-Z` en vez de `Z` para que la parábola salga con el vértice abajo. Esto ya depende de cómo la quieras pintar tú. También puedes jugar con pasar los parámetros en otro orden a `plot_surface()`, por ejemplo `(Z,Y,X)` para que el cilindro salga "vertical".

El resultado es:

[image: Imagen]

Comment: Muchas gracias!!! ;)

Comment: ¿Cómo sería un cilindro terminado en parábola?

Comment: ¿quieres decir ponerle la tapa? Me temo que eso no es posible, pues si es lo que yo estoy entendiendo la superficie que quieres añadirle sería perpendicular la plano XY, y no puedes definir coordenadas en ese caso, o yo no sé cómo hacerlo...